# File does not exist when logged in

Tags: concrete5

I changed the background on a website I made months ago (first edited the homepage, then rolled back, deleted an image and replaced the background image) and now I'm getting a File does not exist when I'm logged in. No error if I'm not and the new background is correcly displayed.

Concrete configuration

```
concrete.version    5.7.4.2
concrete.version_installed  5.7.4.2
concrete.version_db 20150504000000
concrete.installed  true
concrete.site   Lorghi
concrete.locale en_US
concrete.charset    UTF-8
concrete.maintenance_mode   false
concrete.debug.display_errors   true
concrete.debug.detail   debug
concrete.proxy.host null
concrete.proxy.port null
concrete.proxy.user null
concrete.proxy.password null
concrete.upload.extensions  *.flv;*.jpg;*.gif;*.jpeg;*.ico;*.docx;*.xla;*.png;*.psd;*.swf;*.doc;*.txt;*.xls;*.xlsx;*.csv;*.pdf;*.tiff;*.rtf;*.m4a;*.mov;*.wmv;*.mpeg;*.mpg;*.wav;*.3gp;*.avi;*.m4v;*.mp4;*.mp3;*.qt;*.ppt;*.pptx;*.kml;*.xml;*.svg;*.webm;*.ogg;*.ogv
concrete.mail.method    PHP_MAIL
concrete.mail.methods.smtp.server   
concrete.mail.methods.smtp.port 
concrete.mail.methods.smtp.username 
concrete.mail.methods.smtp.password 
concrete.mail.methods.smtp.encryption   
concrete.cache.enabled  true
concrete.cache.lifetime 21600
concrete.cache.overrides    true
concrete.cache.blocks   true
concrete.cache.assets   true
concrete.cache.theme_css    true
concrete.cache.pages    blocks
concrete.cache.doctrine_dev_mode    false
concrete.cache.full_page_lifetime   forever
concrete.cache.full_page_lifetime_value null
concrete.cache.directory    /home/luxuramc/public_html/application/files/cache
concrete.cache.page.directory   /home/luxuramc/public_html/application/files/cache/pages
concrete.cache.page.adapter file
concrete.cache.environment.file environment.cache
concrete.cache.levels.expensive.drivers.0.class \Stash\Driver\Ephemeral
concrete.cache.levels.expensive.drivers.1.class \Stash\Driver\FileSystem
concrete.cache.levels.expensive.drivers.1.options.path  /home/luxuramc/public_html/application/files/cache
concrete.cache.levels.expensive.drivers.1.options.dirPermissions    493
concrete.cache.levels.expensive.drivers.1.options.filePermissions   420
concrete.cache.levels.object.drivers.0.class    \Stash\Driver\Ephemeral
concrete.multilingual.enabled   false
concrete.multilingual.redirect_home_to_default_locale   false
concrete.multilingual.use_browser_detected_locale   false
concrete.multilingual.default_locale    false
concrete.multilingual.default_source_locale en_US
concrete.design.enable_custom   true
concrete.design.enable_layouts  true
concrete.log.emails true
concrete.log.errors true
concrete.log.spam   false
concrete.log.queries.log    false
concrete.log.queries.clear_on_reload    false
concrete.jobs.enable_scheduling true
concrete.filesystem.permissions.file    420
concrete.filesystem.permissions.directory   493
concrete.editor.concrete.enable_filemanager true
concrete.editor.concrete.enable_sitemap true
concrete.editor.plugins.selected.0  concrete5lightbox
concrete.editor.plugins.selected.1  undoredo
concrete.editor.plugins.selected.2  specialcharacters
concrete.editor.plugins.selected.3  table
concrete.email.enabled  true
concrete.email.default.address  concrete5-noreply@lorghi.com
concrete.email.default.name 
concrete.email.form_block.address   false
concrete.marketplace.enabled    true
concrete.marketplace.token  null
concrete.marketplace.site_token null
concrete.marketplace.intelligent_search true
concrete.marketplace.log_requests   false
concrete.external.intelligent_search_help   true
concrete.external.news_overlay  true
concrete.external.news  true
concrete.misc.user_timezones    false
concrete.misc.package_backup_directory  /home/luxuramc/public_html/application/files/trash
concrete.misc.enable_progressive_page_reindex   true
concrete.misc.mobile_theme_id   0
concrete.misc.sitemap_approve_immediately   true
concrete.misc.enable_translate_locale_en_us false
concrete.misc.page_search_index_lifetime    259200
concrete.misc.enable_trash_can  true
concrete.misc.app_version_display_in_header true
concrete.misc.default_jpeg_image_compression    80
concrete.misc.access_entity_updated 1435144589
concrete.misc.latest_version    5.7.5.3
concrete.misc.do_page_reindex_check false
concrete.misc.favicon_fid   222
concrete.theme.compress_preprocessor_output true
concrete.updates.enable_auto_update_core    false
concrete.updates.enable_auto_update_packages    false
concrete.updates.enable_permissions_protection  true
concrete.updates.check_threshold    172800
concrete.updates.services.get_available_updates http://www.concrete5.org/tools/update_core
concrete.updates.services.inspect_update    http://www.concrete5.org/tools/inspect_update
concrete.paths.trash    /!trash
concrete.paths.drafts   /!drafts
concrete.conversations.attachments_pending_file_set Conversation Messages (Pending)
concrete.conversations.attachments_file_set Conversation Messages
concrete.conversations.attachments_enabled  true
concrete.icons.page_template.width  120
concrete.icons.page_template.height 90
concrete.icons.theme_thumbnail.width    120
concrete.icons.theme_thumbnail.height   90
concrete.icons.file_manager_listing.handle  file_manager_listing
concrete.icons.file_manager_listing.width   60
concrete.icons.file_manager_listing.height  60
concrete.icons.file_manager_detail.handle   file_manager_detail
concrete.icons.file_manager_detail.width    400
concrete.icons.user_avatar.width    80
concrete.icons.user_avatar.height   80
concrete.icons.user_avatar.default  /concrete/images/avatar_none.png
concrete.sitemap_xml.file   sitemap.xml
concrete.sitemap_xml.frequency  weekly
concrete.sitemap_xml.priority   0.5
concrete.accessibility.toolbar_titles   false
concrete.accessibility.toolbar_large_font   false
concrete.accessibility.display_help_system  true
concrete.i18n.enabled   true
concrete.i18n.choose_language_login null
concrete.urls.concrete5 http://www.concrete5.org
concrete.urls.concrete5_secure  https://www.concrete5.org
concrete.urls.newsflow  http://newsflow.concrete5.org
concrete.urls.background_feed   //backgroundimages.concrete5.org/wallpaper
concrete.urls.background_feed_secure    https://backgroundimages.concrete5.org/wallpaper
concrete.urls.background_info   http://backgroundimages.concrete5.org/get_image_data.php
concrete.urls.help.developer    http://www.concrete5.org/documentation/developers/5.7/
concrete.urls.help.user http://www.concrete5.org/documentation/using-concrete5-7
concrete.urls.help.forum    http://www.concrete5.org/community/forums
concrete.urls.paths.menu_help_service   /tools/get_remote_help_list/
concrete.urls.paths.theme_preview   /tools/preview_theme/
concrete.urls.paths.site_page   /private/sites
concrete.urls.paths.newsflow_slot_content   /tools/slot_content/
concrete.urls.paths.marketplace.connect /marketplace/connect
concrete.urls.paths.marketplace.connect_success /marketplace/connect/-/connected
concrete.urls.paths.marketplace.connect_validate    /marketplace/connect/-/validate
concrete.urls.paths.marketplace.connect_new_token   /marketplace/connect/-/generate_token
concrete.urls.paths.marketplace.checkout    /cart/-/add/
concrete.urls.paths.marketplace.purchases   /marketplace/connect/-/get_available_licenses
concrete.urls.paths.marketplace.item_information    /marketplace/connect/-/get_item_information
concrete.urls.paths.marketplace.item_free_license   /marketplace/connect/-/enable_free_license
concrete.urls.paths.marketplace.remote_item_list    /marketplace/
concrete.white_label.logo   false
concrete.white_label.name   false
concrete.white_label.dashboard_background   null
concrete.session.name   CONCRETE5
concrete.session.handler    file
concrete.session.max_lifetime   7200
concrete.session.cookie.cookie_path false
concrete.session.cookie.cookie_lifetime 0
concrete.session.cookie.cookie_domain   false
concrete.session.cookie.cookie_secure   false
concrete.session.cookie.cookie_httponly false
concrete.user.registration.enabled  false
concrete.user.registration.type disabled
concrete.user.registration.captcha  true
concrete.user.registration.email_registration   false
concrete.user.registration.validate_email   false
concrete.user.registration.approval false
concrete.user.registration.notification false
concrete.user.gravatar.enabled  false
concrete.user.gravatar.max_level    0
concrete.user.gravatar.image_set    0
concrete.user.group.badge.default_point_value   50
concrete.user.profiles_enabled  false
concrete.user.timezones_enabled false
concrete.user.username.maximum  64
concrete.user.username.minimum  3
concrete.user.username.allow_spaces false
concrete.user.password.maximum  128
concrete.user.password.minimum  5
concrete.user.password.hash_portable    false
concrete.user.password.hash_cost_log2   12
concrete.user.private_messages.throttle_max 20
concrete.user.private_messages.throttle_max_timespan    15
concrete.spam.whitelist_group   0
concrete.spam.notify_email  
concrete.security.ban.ip.enabled    true
concrete.security.ban.ip.attempts   5
concrete.security.ban.ip.time   300
concrete.security.ban.ip.length 10
concrete.permissions.forward_to_login   true
concrete.permissions.model  advanced
concrete.permissions.page_permission_collection_id  true
concrete.seo.tracking.code  
concrete.seo.tracking.code_position bottom
concrete.seo.exclude_words  a, an, as, at, before, but, by, for, from, is, in, into, like, of, off, on, onto, per, since, than, the, this, that, to, up, via, with
concrete.seo.url_rewriting  1
concrete.seo.url_rewriting_all  false
concrete.seo.redirect_to_canonical_url  1
concrete.seo.canonical_url  http://lorghi.com
concrete.seo.canonical_ssl_url  https://lorghi.com
concrete.seo.trailing_slash false
concrete.seo.title_format   %1$s :: %2$s
concrete.seo.title_segment_separator    ::
concrete.seo.page_path_separator    -
concrete.seo.group_name_separator   /
concrete.seo.segment_max_length 128
concrete.seo.paging_string  ccm_paging_p
concrete.limits.sitemap_pages   100
concrete.limits.delete_pages    10
concrete.limits.copy_pages  10
concrete.limits.page_search_index_batch 200
concrete.limits.job_queue_batch 10
concrete.limits.style_customizer.size_min   -50
concrete.limits.style_customizer.size_max   200
```

Server/Request Data

```
HTTP_ACCEPT text/html,application/xhtml+xml,application/xml;q=0.9,image/webp,*/*;q=0.8
HTTP_ACCEPT_ENCODING    gzip, deflate, sdch
HTTP_ACCEPT_LANGUAGE    it-IT,it;q=0.8,en-GB;q=0.6,en;q=0.4
HTTP_CONNECTION keep-alive
CONTENT_LENGTH  0
HTTP_COOKIE ccmAuthUserHash=1%3Aconcrete%3Ae0ba0574b510506d44ed435cf3a37c43; CONCRETE5=i1091ikj0adqo0l2aq9gsi2ql6; ConcreteSitemap-select=; ConcreteSitemap-expand=1; ConcreteSitemap-active=172; ConcreteSitemap-focus=
HTTP_HOST   lorghi.com
HTTP_REFERER    http://lorghi.com/index.php/dashboard/system/environment/debug/debug_saved
HTTP_USER_AGENT Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; WOW64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/47.0.2526.64 Safari/537.36 Vivaldi/1.0.334.3
HTTP_UPGRADE_INSECURE_REQUESTS  1
UNIQUE_ID   VlgwwlLAQIEADtW00mcAAACS
PATH    /usr/local/bin:/usr/bin:/bin
LD_LIBRARY_PATH /usr/local/apache/lib
SERVER_SIGNATURE    
SERVER_SOFTWARE Apache
SERVER_NAME lorghi.com
SERVER_ADDR 82.192.64.157
SERVER_PORT 80
REMOTE_ADDR 2.32.30.97
DOCUMENT_ROOT   /home/luxuramc/public_html
REQUEST_SCHEME  http
CONTEXT_PREFIX  
CONTEXT_DOCUMENT_ROOT   /home/luxuramc/public_html
SERVER_ADMIN    webmaster@lorghi.com
SCRIPT_FILENAME /home/luxuramc/public_html/index.php
REMOTE_PORT 51394
SERVER_PROTOCOL HTTP/1.1
REQUEST_METHOD  GET
QUERY_STRING    cID=1
REQUEST_URI /index.php?cID=1
SCRIPT_NAME /index.php
PHP_SELF    /index.php
REQUEST_TIME_FLOAT  1448620226.2351
REQUEST_TIME    1448620226
```

Imagine\Exception\InvalidArgumentException thrown with message "File  does not exist."

```
Stacktrace:
#22 Imagine\Exception\InvalidArgumentException in /home/luxuramc/public_html/concrete/vendor/imagine/imagine/lib/Imagine/Image/AbstractImagine.php:67
#21 Imagine\Image\AbstractImagine:checkPath in /home/luxuramc/public_html/concrete/vendor/imagine/imagine/lib/Imagine/Gd/Imagine.php:86
#20 Imagine\Gd\Imagine:open in /home/luxuramc/public_html/concrete/src/Support/Facade/Facade.php:116
#19 Concrete\Core\Support\Facade\Facade:__callStatic in /home/luxuramc/public_html/concrete/src/Legacy/ImageHelper.php:97
#18 Concrete\Core\Support\Facade\Image:open in /home/luxuramc/public_html/concrete/src/Legacy/ImageHelper.php:97
#17 Concrete\Core\Legacy\ImageHelper:getThumbnail in /home/luxuramc/public_html/packages/background_image_overlay/blocks/background_image_overlay/view.php:13
#16 include in /home/luxuramc/public_html/concrete/src/Block/View/BlockView.php:234
#15 Concrete\Core\Block\View\BlockView:renderViewContents in /home/luxuramc/public_html/concrete/src/View/AbstractView.php:123
#14 Concrete\Core\View\AbstractView:render in /home/luxuramc/public_html/concrete/src/Area/Area.php:862
#13 Concrete\Core\Area\Area:display in /home/luxuramc/public_html/concrete/src/Area/GlobalArea.php:118
#12 Concrete\Core\Area\GlobalArea:display in /home/luxuramc/public_html/application/themes/elementalcustom/elements/header.php:15
#11 include in /home/luxuramc/public_html/concrete/src/View/View.php:74
#10 Concrete\Core\View\View:inc in /home/luxuramc/public_html/application/themes/elementalcustom/default.php:3
#9 include in /home/luxuramc/public_html/concrete/src/View/View.php:74
#8 Concrete\Core\View\View:inc in /home/luxuramc/public_html/application/themes/elementalcustom/full.php:3
#7 include in /home/luxuramc/public_html/concrete/src/View/View.php:189
#6 Concrete\Core\View\View:renderViewContents in /home/luxuramc/public_html/concrete/src/View/AbstractView.php:123
#5 Concrete\Core\View\AbstractView:render in /home/luxuramc/public_html/concrete/src/Routing/DispatcherRouteCallback.php:24
#4 Concrete\Core\Routing\DispatcherRouteCallback:sendResponse in /home/luxuramc/public_html/concrete/src/Routing/DispatcherRouteCallback.php:213
#3 Concrete\Core\Routing\DispatcherRouteCallback:execute in /home/luxuramc/public_html/concrete/src/Application/Application.php:369
#2 Concrete\Core\Application\Application:dispatch in /home/luxuramc/public_html/concrete/bootstrap/start.php:284
#1 require in /home/luxuramc/public_html/concrete/dispatcher.php:36
#0 require in /home/luxuramc/public_html/index.php:2
```

/home/luxuramc/public_html/concrete/vendor/imagine/imagine/lib/Imagine/Image/AbstractImagine.php

```
if (is_object($path) && method_exists($path, '__toString')) {
    $path = (string) $path;
}

$handle = @fopen($path, 'r');

if (false === $handle) {
    throw new InvalidArgumentException(sprintf('File %s does not exist.', $path));
}
```

/home/luxuramc/public_html/concrete/vendor/imagine/imagine/lib/Imagine/Gd/Imagine.php

```
}

/**
 * {@inheritdoc}
 */
public function open($path)
{
    $path = $this->checkPath($path);
    $data = @file_get_contents($path);
```

/home/luxuramc/public_html/concrete/src/Support/Facade/Facade.php

```
  }
    switch (count($args))
    {
        case 0:
            return $instance->$method();

        case 1:
            return $instance->$method($args[0]);

        case 2:
```

/home/luxuramc/public_html/concrete/src/Legacy/ImageHelper.php

```
            . '.' . $fh->getExtension($obj);
    }

    if (!file_exists(Config::get('concrete.cache.directory') . '/' . $filename)) {
        if ($obj instanceof File) {
            $image = \Image::load($fr->read());
        } else {
            $image = \Image::open($obj);
        }
        // create image there
```

/home/luxuramc/public_html/concrete/src/Legacy/ImageHelper.php

```
            . '.' . $fh->getExtension($obj);
    }

    if (!file_exists(Config::get('concrete.cache.directory') . '/' . $filename)) {
        if ($obj instanceof File) {
            $image = \Image::load($fr->read());
        } else {
            $image = \Image::open($obj);
        }
        // create image there
```

/home/luxuramc/public_html/packages/background_image_overlay/blocks/background_image_overlay/view.php

```
$localPath = $urlHelper->getBlockTypeAssetsURL($blockType);
?>

<?php 
$imageHelper = Core::make('helper/image');
$file = File::getByID($fID);

$bgLarge = $imageHelper->getThumbnail($file, 1600, 999, false);
$bgMedium = $imageHelper->getThumbnail($file, 1300, 999, false);
$bgSmall = $imageHelper->getThumbnail($file, 1000, 999, false);
```

/home/luxuramc/public_html/concrete/src/Block/View/BlockView.php

```
}

public function renderViewContents($scopeItems)
{
    extract($scopeItems);
    if (!$this->outputContent) {
        ob_start();
        include $this->template;
        $this->outputContent = ob_get_contents();
        ob_end_clean();
```

/home/luxuramc/public_html/concrete/src/View/AbstractView.php

```
    if ($this instanceof View) {
        $this->setRequestInstance($this);
    }
    $this->start($state);
    $this->setupRender();
    $this->startRender();
    $scopeItems = $this->getScopeItems();
    $contents = $this->renderViewContents($scopeItems);
    $contents = $this->postProcessViewContents($contents);
    $response = $this->finishRender($contents);
```

/home/luxuramc/public_html/concrete/src/Area/Area.php

```
        $bv = new BlockView($b);
        $bv->setAreaObject($this);
        $p = new Permissions($b);
        if ($p->canViewBlock()) {
            if (!$c->isEditMode()) {
                echo $this->enclosingStart;
            }
            $bv->render('view');
            if (!$c->isEditMode()) {
                echo $this->enclosingEnd;
```

/home/luxuramc/public_html/concrete/src/Area/GlobalArea.php

```
    unset($blocksTmp);
    return $blocks;
}

public function display()
{
    $c = Page::getCurrentPage();
    parent::display($c);
}
```

/home/luxuramc/public_html/application/themes/elementalcustom/elements/header.php

```
<header>
    <div class="container">
        <div class="row">
            <div class="col-sm-4 col-xs-6">
                <?php
                $a = new GlobalArea('Header Site Title');
                $a->display();
                ?>
            </div>
```

/home/luxuramc/public_html/concrete/src/View/View.php

```
}

public function inc($file, $args = array())
{
    extract($args);
    extract($this->getScopeItems());
    $env = Environment::get();
    include $env->getPath(DIRNAME_THEMES.'/'.$this->themeHandle.'/'.$file, $this->pkgHandle);
}
```

/home/luxuramc/public_html/application/themes/elementalcustom/default.php

```
<?php
defined('C5_EXECUTE') or die("Access Denied.");
$this->inc('elements/header.php'); ?>

<main>
<?php
$a = new Area('Main');
$a->enableGridContainer();
$a->display($c);
?>
```

/home/luxuramc/public_html/concrete/src/View/View.php

```
}

public function inc($file, $args = array())
{
    extract($args);
    extract($this->getScopeItems());
    $env = Environment::get();
    include $env->getPath(DIRNAME_THEMES.'/'.$this->themeHandle.'/'.$file, $this->pkgHandle);
}
```

/home/luxuramc/public_html/application/themes/elementalcustom/full.php

```
<?php
defined('C5_EXECUTE') or die("Access Denied.");
$this->inc('default.php');
```

/home/luxuramc/public_html/concrete/src/View/View.php

```
        $innerContent = ob_get_contents();
        ob_end_clean();
    }

    if (file_exists($this->template)) {
        ob_start();
        $this->onBeforeGetContents();
        include $this->template;
        $contents = ob_get_contents();
        $this->onAfterGetContents();
```

/home/luxuramc/public_html/concrete/src/View/AbstractView.php

```
    if ($this instanceof View) {
        $this->setRequestInstance($this);
    }
    $this->start($state);
    $this->setupRender();
    $this->startRender();
    $scopeItems = $this->getScopeItems();
    $contents = $this->renderViewContents($scopeItems);
    $contents = $this->postProcessViewContents($contents);
    $response = $this->finishRender($contents);
```

/home/luxuramc/public_html/concrete/src/Routing/DispatcherRouteCallback.php

```
use Session;

class DispatcherRouteCallback extends RouteCallback
{

    protected function sendResponse(View $v, $code = 200)
    {
        $contents = $v->render();
        $response = new Response($contents, $code);
```

/home/luxuramc/public_html/concrete/src/Routing/DispatcherRouteCallback.php

```
            }
        }
    }

    // we update the current page with the one bound to this controller.
    $request->setCurrentPage($c);

    return $this->sendResponse($view);
}
```

/home/luxuramc/public_html/concrete/src/Application/Application.php

```
            $request->attributes->add($matcher->match($path));
            $matched = $matcher->match($path);
            $route = $collection->get($matched['_route']);
            Route::setRequest($request);
            $response = Route::execute($route, $matched);
        } catch(ResourceNotFoundException $e) {
            $callback = new DispatcherRouteCallback('dispatcher');
            $response = $callback->execute($request);
        }
    }
```

/home/luxuramc/public_html/concrete/bootstrap/start.php

```
\Events::dispatch('on_before_dispatch');

/**
 * ----------------------------------------------------------------------------
 * Get the response to the current request
 * ----------------------------------------------------------------------------
 */
$response = $cms->dispatch($request);
/**
 * ----------------------------------------------------------------------------
```

/home/luxuramc/public_html/concrete/dispatcher.php

```
/**
 * ----------------------------------------------------------------------------
 * Begin concrete5 startup.
 * ----------------------------------------------------------------------------
 */
$cms = require $__DIR__ . '/bootstrap/start.php';
```

/home/luxuramc/public_html/index.php

```
<?php
require('concrete/dispatcher.php');
```

Answer (score 0):

Updating to the latest release should fix this issue.